# the Ninject's Singleton scope is similar with the static field?

Tags: static, ninject

In the past, i use original reflect the class and set to a static field, as follows

```
public class ServiceHelper{
    private static IFoo _iFoo=null;
    public static IFoo Foo{
        get{
            if(_iFoo==null)
            {
              _iFoo=Activator.CreateInstance("assembly") as IFoo;

             }
             return _iFoo;
           }
    }

}
```

and now we are using Ninject

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesInPath("assembilypath")
.SelectAllClasses()
.BindDefaultInterface().Configure(binding => binding.InSingletonScope()));
```

questions:

1. the two methods are the same?
2. Ninject will load the assembly only once?
3. if change the assembly, can ninject detected and reload the new assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes there will be exactly one shared instance of Foo
2. The .NET Framework will load each assembly at most one time (per AppDomain).
3. No - you will have to restart.